Slow Ember build in docker container
I'm attempting to Dockerize my local development setup to make it much simpler to onboard new developers and ensure a common local environment for all. But i am running into build performance issues where the app build compilation just stops in the middle and doesn't progress further. I tried the same with a sample ember app and there is no issues with it. The repo that i am working on is quite big and has 100s of components. The build compilation is very slow only in the container and normal in the host machine.
This is my dockerfile:
# BASE IMAGE Amazon Linux:2
FROM amazonlinux:2

# Set up workdir
ENV APP_DIR /app
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
VOLUME [$APP_DIR]

# INSTALL dependencies
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y git sudo wget curl cups-libs && \
    yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools" && \
    curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash - && \
    yum install -y nodejs python-devel openssl-devel && \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

# INSTALL Google chrome stable
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm && \
  yum install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm && \
  yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

# INSTALL NVM and Ember CLI
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash && source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install 12.16.3 && \
    npm install ember-cli@3.8.3 -g

RUN echo 'source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 12.16.3' >> /root/.bashrc

# install watchman
RUN git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git && \
  cd watchman && \
  git stash && \
  git checkout -f v4.9.0 && \
  ./autogen.sh && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN /bin/bash -c "if ! yarn --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then npm install -g yarn; fi && source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 12.16.3" && \
  yarn global add bower && \
  echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc

EXPOSE 4200 7153

CMD ["bash"]

Available cpu cores: 12 (M3 Mac pro)
I have allocated 12 cpus to the podman default machine and no limit set for the individual container.
Allocated ram: 12gb
Available ram: 18gb
Process details from top:
Tasks: 274 total,   2 running, 272 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.1 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :  11924.1 total,   5362.0 free,   5765.5 used,   1022.6 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   6158.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                      
   4262 root      20   0   11.1g   4.4g  34964 R  99.7  37.5   6:09.23 ember                                                                                                                                                                        
      1 root      20   0   77288  27420  10764 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.93 systemd                                                                                                                                                                      
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd

Note: I even tried the dockerfile we use for CI pipeline which runs the unit tests for the PRs and that is also very slow and build doesnt get completed. is this an issue with mac osxfs?

what version of podman are you using? Have you tried downgrading the version of it? (try 5.0.0)

Why are you installing Node 14 at the beginning then using NVM to install Node 12 ? In addition, you shouldn't use sudo in your dockerfile, you are already root

@Damzaky with v5.0, the process is not getting hanged up anymore, but I am facing an issue with npm install (https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/22471). it can be resolved with few extra commands executed manually but the suggestion is to use v5.1 which has the same hang up issue as the latest version. is there no option to upgrade beyond v5.0 ?

unfortunately, I don't know, you need to do trial errors on many things here (tweaking versions of both podman or others), or just use another device (like macbook intels)

Any chance you can move to node 22+ and vite? -- everything you're using is long out of support

@NullVoxPopuli it is a legacy codebase and not easy to migrate. we are working on gradual shift to microfrontends which should make things easier down the line :)
